# How can I transfer my US License to the UK?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilot-certification, caa-uk-regulations

I'm thinking of moving over to the UK to fly for British Airways since they only ask for 500 hours Pilot-in-Command time to become a First Officer.

I currently hold a CPL and am Instrument Rated. I was wondering what the process was to transfer my FAA license to a UK one.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact British Airways and ask them. If they want you, they will tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to follow the "route 1" conversion requirements listed here before applying to the airline:

https://www.caa.co.uk/commercial-industry/pilot-licences/non-uk-licences/third-country-cpl-and-atpl-licence-conversion-requirements-from-1-january-2023/

Essentially it will involve sitting the ATPL theory exams (with a 650 hour theory course, unless you've already got ATPL theory credit on your license), some practical flight training before a skills test.

The validation pathway is not for you as that expires after one year.

Of course you should not begin to think about this process unless you already have the unrestricted right to work in the UK. That is a criteria on the BA website, suggesting they cannot sponsor you for a working visa.

Answer (score 1):

The details of validating an ICAO-compliant licence for work in the UK is detailed on the CAA website

https://www.caa.co.uk/commercial-industry/pilot-licences/non-uk-licences/validating-an-icao-licence-for-work/

> Validating an ICAO licence for work allows you to fly for remuneration on non-commercial operations, commercial air transport or other commercial activities using your ICAO licence.

There are basically the requirements you probably expect; medical validity, proficiency check, and of course a fee! Most of this will probably be arranged by your new employer.